# SQLAlchemy migrating MySQL followers system to PostgreSQL issue

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-schema, flask-sqlalchemy

Today I decided to move my fairly new project to PostgreSQL, but I've encountered a few issues down the road, one of which is:

Below is a perfectly normal, functional MySQL model for a follower / followed system, however for some reason I keep getting SQLAlchemy errors:

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Relationship User.followed could not determine any
 unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on join condition and remote_side a
rguments.  Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those eleme
nts of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.

```
followers = db.Table(
    'followers',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, 
                           default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, 
                           default=datetime.datetime.utcnow,
                           onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

class User(Base, UserJsonSerializer, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True,)
    followed = db.relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
        lazy='dynamic'
    )
```

I am very new to PostgreSQL so I am rather lost as to what is the issue here, and since this is a fairly complicated relationship, I am even more at loss what to do.

Comment: while formatting your code, i found that the line `updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow,` has a dangling brace. Could you fix that line. thanks.

Comment: Right you are, my bad, while copying from my source files I missed a line, fixed now. :)

Comment: The error you are getting does not come from postgresql, which seems strange if the only thing you have done is change DB backend. What version of sqlalchemy are you using? Is it the same in both cases? I notice that using primaryjoin/secondaryjoin seems not to be required in later versions

Comment: SqlAlchemy 2.0 on Python 3.5.0b4, above code worked fine with MariaDB 10.0, but breaks with PostgreSQL. My MySQL dialect for SQLA is PyMySQL and PostgreSQL dialect is py-postgresql

Comment: Apparently I goofed up, I ment SqlAlchemy 1.0.8 and Flask-SqlAlchemy 2.0, not SqlAlchemy 2.0...

Comment: So nobody has comes to this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

So I found a solution myself, not sure if it will work but so far the error seems to be gone.
Cheers.

```
    followed = db.relationship('User',
                               secondary=followers,
                               foreign_keys=[followers.c.follower_id])

    followers = db.relationship('User',
                                secondary=followers,
                                foreign_keys=[followers.c.followed_id])
```